# How to access Wagtail snippets menu

Tags: wagtail

I am running Wagtail v2.8 and I want to use snippets. The documentation says

> You can access the Snippets menu by clicking on the ‘Snippets’ link in the left-hand menu bar.

Mine shows no 'Snippets' items. I have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'wagtail.snippets',
    ...]
```

[image]

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [register a model as a snippet](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/snippets.html#snippet-models) using `@register_snippet`.  If you `ForeignKey` to a Django model and need to choose it in the Wagtail admin, you can use `SnippetChooserPanel` in your `content_panels` or `panels` definition:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#module-wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers

Depending on what you need to do, you might find that using a [site setting](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/settings.html#defining-settings) is more appropriate.